# Find total cost after deletion of minimum node one by one

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given a sequence of n distinct integers a[0],a[1],a[2],...,a[n-1]. In each iteration you pick the minimum number and delete it, the cost of deleting the minimum number is the number of numbers to the right of it. Repeat this n number of times. Given ai’s implement O(n log n) algorithm to compute the total cost of n iterations.

For example: A[] = 6,2,8,4,9,3

cost == 4+0+1+2+1+0 = 8;

I know I have to use BST here but I am not able to get the idea of how to get cost after deletion of node.

Comment: Hint: use `std:::set`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this please.

Comment: These complexities have little to do with C++. They are language-agnostic rather. In any case, it doesn't matter that your node is minimal, the cost of deleting it stays the same. It depends on the used datatype though, which is an assumption/implication not mentioned in your question. Also, one thing to be careful with is names: You have `n` distinct integers and you're removing in `n` iterations. Are those the same `n`?

Comment: Background to the `std::set`: It operates internally on a partially balanced binary search tree (usually a red-black tree) which guarantees insertion, finding and removal of elements in `O(log n)`. You fill the tree with `n` elements, each with `O(log n)`, giving you `O(n log n)` in total. Removing `r` (<= `n`!) elements is then `O(r log n)`, sum of both giving again `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the cost of an element is exactly the number of elements to the right of this element that is greater than it. You can maintain an `std::set` and scan the array from right to left. Each time you meet an element, compute its cost using the `std::set` then add this element to the `std::set`. This is an O(n log n) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to use BST here

Not necessarily (unless explicitly required by the task):

You can in advance sort the array in descending order in `O(n log n)` (e. g. in place with [intro sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) as `std::sort` does), then removing cost is `O(1)` for all elements at once, assuming it suffices just to move the end pointer into the array (e. g. with `std::vector`, which does so internally) – or possibly `n - r` with `r` the number of elements to be removed, if you are required to copy the remaining values into a new array.

If you rely on original order you can tag each value with its original index (e. g. `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned long, size_t>>`) and restore the order by again sorting on the indices, again `O(n log n)` (actually even e bit less as we have a reduced `n` here...). If you need to modify the original array in place you might add another array with indices only and while sorting do all operations on both arrays in parallel.

In total you then get:
`O(n log n + (either n - r or 1) + (n - r) log (n - r)) = O(n log n)`
with `r` <= `n` the number of elements to be removed.